# Where to find repository of code deployed for Alexa skills?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

To develop alexa skill I have created a project and uploaded to alexa skill's code tab and then deployed. Here is the image for reference to where code is available:
[image: code repo]

So the code is versioned using git, which means somewhere in aws all the commits can be viewed.
So where we can find that? I have checked the code star and code commit in my aws account as well as the default account created by alexa which we do not have access to. Image attached for reference.
[image: access denied code commit dashboard with alexa default role]

Please help in clarifying this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is stored in an AWS CodeCommit repository *but* you can only access/clone it via the [ASK CLI](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html).

The [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/build-a-skill-end-to-end-using-an-alexa-hosted-skill.html#setup) says: *When you create the skill, the service also sets up an AWS CodeCommit repository for managing your code, which you can access by using the ASK CLI to edit your skill.*